Exceptions for android 6/5 users after updating to latest version Google Play Billing Library (7.1.1)
Recently I have updated my app to the latest Google Play Billing Library (7.1.1). After that I see multiple crash in Firebase crashlytics for users with Android 6 and 5 when they try to initiate billing flow process:
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
No virtual method stream()Ljava/util/stream/Stream; in class Ljava/util/AbstractCollection; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.AbstractCollection' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
com.android.billingclient.api.BillingFlowParams.zzq (com.android.billingclient:billing@@7.1.1:21)
com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl.launchBillingFlow (com.android.billingclient:billing@@7.1.1:133)

/**
 * Launch the billing flow
 */
public void launchBillingFlow(SkuDetails skuDetails) {
    Log.d(TAG, "launchBillingFlow()");

    if (null != skuDetails) {
        BillingFlowParams.Builder billingFlowParamsBuilder = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder();
        billingFlowParamsBuilder.setSkuDetails(skuDetails);
        BillingResult br = mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParamsBuilder.build());
        if (br.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            mBillingFlowInProcess = true;
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Billing failed: + " + br.getDebugMessage());
        }
    }
}

Anybody has the same problem? Maybe there is any solution to this problem?
P.S. I have added the following in proguard file but it didnt help:
-keep class com.android.vending.billing.**

java.util.stream requires desugaring. Have you enabled desugaring for your project? https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#library-desugaring

By the way, is there a way to reproduce this thing on emulators? All emulators with Android 6/5 have no Google Play...

I have the same issue. Were you able to completely fix it by adding desugaring as mentioned in Blue Ocean's answer?

@A.J. If you don't need the features of PBL 7.1.1, you can use PBL 7.0.0 and wait for a fixed version from Google.

Thanks @BlueOcean, I've pushed update with desugaring for now. It costs 200kb increase in build size though. If and when googles fixes it, I'll remove the desugaring. Though they might decide to just drop support for android 5/6 in future.

This issue only occurs in Play Billing Library 7.1.1. It does not occur in Play Billing Library 7.0.0.
If you don't need the features of PBL 7.1.1, you can use PBL 7.0.0 and wait for a fixed version from Google.
This issue has also been reported in the issue tracker, but there has been no official response yet.
[Play Billing Library 7.1.1] launchBillingFlow() does not work on Android 6 (Marshmallow)
As @Robert mentioned, Play Billing Library 7.1.1 seems to use classes available starting with Android 7 (Java 8).
Luckily, we have an Android 6 test device. We tested it by turning on the desugaring option in build.gradle.kts as below and confirmed that the issue is resolved.
I think this should be documented in the Play Billing Library 7.1.1 release notes.
build.gradle.kts
android {
    ...

    compileOptions {
        isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...

    implementation( "com.android.billingclient:billing:7.1.1" )

    coreLibraryDesugaring( "com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.1.2" )
}

Further investigations
BillingFlowParams.Builder.build() calls this.zzc.forEach(new zzce()); for null check

this.zzc is a List set by setProductDetailsParamsList()
List.forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) and Consumer => Added in API level 24

